# Is there a connection between $a \nmid b$ and $ax + by = d$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I should point out that I am not very good at mathematics. For example if $3 \nmid n$ is it true that $3x + ny = 1$? If $a \nmid b$ then $a$ and $b$ have no common factors. However $14 \nmid 21$ but $\text{gcd}(14,21) =7$ so does that mean that $14x +  21y = 7$. **The question**: Is there a connection between $a \nmid b$ and $ax + by = d$ and how do you express $a \nmid b$ as $ax + by = d$ (that is if that is possible).

Comment: If $a,b$ have a common factor then the least positive integer expressible as $ax+by$ is their gcd.  The condition $a\nmid b$ is not sufficiently informative; it can be true with their gcd as 1  or gcd > 1.

Answer (score 1):

The equation $aX+bY = d$ can be solved in integers if and only if $\gcd(a,b)\mid d$. A relevant keyword is [Bézout identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity).

The condition $a \nmid b$ does not guarantee this in general, yet if $a$ is a prime number  then $a \nmid b$ is equivalent to $\gcd(a,b)=1$.

On the question on how to express $a \nmid b$ via such an equation, one could say that the following are equivalent:

- $a \nmid b$
- there exists a $d$ that is not a multiple of $a$ such that $aX+bY = d$ has a solution.
- there exists some $1 \le d \le |a|-1$ such that $aX+bY = d$ has a solution.